# How to design a many to one mapping in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have the following list of entitites

1.Orders
2.User
3.Products
4.Features

The order item consists of the following things

OrderId, userIds, sku, featureIds as list

I want to filter the orders based on featuresIds and userId. currently what I am going is maintaining userId as primary key. Fetching the orders based on the userId and filtering the records based on featureId in code. But if the number of features are more the record size increases and the performance becomes slower can we do something about. I explored ideas like storing range as featureIds but since we have more than 90 features for every record it becomes difficult for us to repeat all the records is there any alternate approach instead of filtering in code because the response time has become more than 1 sec now from dynamodb

PartionKey: UserId

Comment: Here you can do this with the help of the "FilterExpression" dynamodb function

Comment: its possible i have 100 orders and featureId since its a list cannot be made as range key. How can i filter then ?

Answer (score 2):

| PK | SK | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USER#123 | USER#123 | USER DATA |
| USER#123 | FEAT#123 | SOME DATA |
| USER#123 | FEAT#345 | SOME DATA |
| USER#123 | FEAT#917 | SOME DATA |

##### Give me the user info where user is 123

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE PK='USER#123' AND SK='USER#123'
```

##### Give me the item where user is 123 and feature is 345:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE PK='USER#123' AND SK='FEAT#345'
```

##### Give me all the features for user 123

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE PK='USER#123' AND SK BEGINS_WITH('FEAT')
```

Comment: The suggested approach is good. But my access pattern is get me all the orders for user and also match the feature Ids.
Input is UserId , featureId or featureprefix. its more like many features mapped to an order and a user mapped to multiple orders ?

the above approach you mentioned i should make two queries one for list of users matching the feature prefix and second one for getting user details ?

Comment: i have one more question if have 80 features for an order and 100 orders matching the userId 
sample records

user1, ORDER 1, featureIds
user1, order 2, featureIds 
How can i fetch based on  access pattern matching userId and featureId and since item size is becoming large query is becoming slow in PT how to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly your data is like:

```
{
  orderID: "order_1",
  customerID: "customer_1",
  products: [
    { 
       productID: "product_1"
    }
  ],
  features: [
    "feature_green_1",
    "feature_plastic_2",
    ....
    "feature_yellow_n"
  ]
}
```

And you want to ask the question:

- "Get me all orders for customer_1 which have feature_plastic_2 or have features starting with feature_green"

And what you're doing now is asking "Give me all orders for customer_1" and then filtering in code and the response times from DynamoDB are too high (plus you likely have increased memory requirements and processing times).

What do you care about when it comes to your options?

- Do you can about the size of any one table?
- Do you care about maintaining multiple tables?
- Do you care about making multiple calls to DynamoDB?

If you do care about the size of your tables and don't mind multiple tables, use a secondary index table.

One possible way to do this (there are other permutations that have their own pros/cons)

```
Primary Index:
Pk: customer_id
SK: order_id
data: the good stuff

Secondary Index:
Pk: customer_id
Sk: feature_id
order_ids: array<order_id>
```

You can then ask the query the secondary index for customers with features and get back a set of order ids.

Dedupe those in code and then make a second request to your Primary index for the customer and order ids.

Comment: I tried this approach since the data size of the item is high its still taking time what should i do? the nested object product contains more than 100 items. the total size of each item is 7kb its taking more time for fetching each items separately